# What does session_write_close do when calling it before a query?

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering what `session_write_close()` does. I find the manual a little bit vague.
I have some pretty big `SELECT` queries. Before those `SELECT` queries I'm calling `session_write_close()`, and after the queries I'm calling `session_start()` again.

You might wonder why I do this, if I don't and an user is executing one of those `SELECT` queries and aborts them (trying to opening another page for example), the user can't open the new page (or has to wait pretty long). I think because the script is waiting until the large query is done.

**So my question(s):**
What exactly does `session_write_close()` do when calling it before a query?

Why doesn't the user have to wait (with `session_write_close()` before the query) when opening a new page, when aborting the query?



Thanks in advance

Comment: `session_write_close()` basically **writes** and **closes** the session.

Comment: @Jack I read that, does it affect the users session when calling `session_start` again? And does it affect the query?

Comment: Your users are not aborting the query.  If they close the browser or navigate somewhere else, or simply press the escape key, that only affects the client.  The server knows nothing about this.  Once the server code finishes executing it returns html to the client that requested it.  The client might no longer be waiting for that html, but nothing actually breaks.

Comment: @DanBracuk Actually the server can tell if it can't write a response of any kind. http://php.net/connection_aborted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that the below graph helps to understand what goes on; we're talking about a session for the same user (i.e. same session id):

```
script a             | lock |    script b
---------------------+------+-----------------
start

open session      <- | yes  |    start

do stuff

close session     -> | yes  | -> open session

do heavy queries     |      |    do stuff

open session      <- | yes  | <- script ended

script ended      -> | no   |
```

Closing the session when you're not going to use it, be it for a while or until the script ends, makes it available for another script.

Note that once the other script has run the session data may have been altered.

Comment: Can I however still access the session variables after calling session_write_close?

Comment: Updated session variables only become available *after* `session_start`.

Answer (score 12):

PHP's default session store is simply a file on the hard disk. I.e., the contents of `$_SESSION` are simply dumped into a file on disk. When you call `session_start`, that file is read and `$_SESSION` is populated, when the script ends, `$_SESSION` is written back to disk.

It's easy to get into a classic race condition here. If two requests come in in parallel, and two independent scripts read from the file, and then sometime later the two scripts write back to the file... which one wins? What will be the content of the file, and may there have been some data overwritten?

The solution to this is file locking. PHP acquires a lock on the session file, preventing anyone else from reading or writing to it until the lock is lifted. If two parallel scripts are trying to acquire a lock at the same time, one of them has to wait until the other is done. That's what you're seeing.

`session_write_close` explicitly writes the `$_SESSION` content to disk and relinquishes the lock.

Comment: Thanks gave you an upvote. Jack was a little bit earlier with also a clear explanation.

Comment: Can I however still access the session variables after calling session_write_close?

Comment: I'm not sure whether `$_SESSION` is purged or not when calling the function, the manual doesn't say anything about it. Try it. You should be very careful to only *read* from it though, not write to it, as long as the session is closed. Otherwise you may lose your written data.